# Why curl does not work in symfony controller?

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I use the same curl code in symfony command and symfony controller, in command it works while in controller it doesn't. Does anybody know why?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Did you setup ext-curl for both the cli and whatever php you're using to serve your content? (generally apache or fpm)

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get an error? A null result?

Comment: Also please check if `$url` is defined in both cases and it is the same

Comment: Put an error_reporting(-1); in front of that.

Answer (score 1):

Check server configuration first. Otherwise, did you forget to declare the request method?

`CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>'PUT'`

hope it works